# how to deploing spring-boot micro-service

Tags: java

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'welcomePageHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'welcomePageHandlerMapping' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'taskRepository' defined in com.book.todo.repository.TaskRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.book.todo.repository.TaskRepository.findByAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.book.todo.repository.TaskRepository.findByAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); No property 'all' found for type 'Task'

`package com.book.todo.entity;`

`import jakarta.persistence.Column; import jakarta.persistence.Entity; import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue; import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType; import jakarta.persistence.Id;`your text `import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank; import lombok.Data;`

`@Entity @Data public class Task` `{`

```
`@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;`

@Column
@NotBlank
private String name;

@Column
@NotBlank
private String description;
```

`}`

`package com.book.todo.repository;`

`import java.util.Collection; import java.util.List; import java.util.Optional;`

`import org.springframework.data.domain.Page; import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable; import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository; import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor; import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query; import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor; import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param; import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource; import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;`

`import com.book.todo.entity.Task;`

`@RepositoryRestResource(path = "task", collectionResourceRel = "tasks") public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Task>,QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Task>{`

```
Page<Task>findyIdln(@Param(value = "id")List<Integer> eventid, Pageable Pageable);
Page<Task>findynameln(@Param("name")Collection<String> name, Pageable Pageable);

@Query(name="Task.findByName", nativeQuery = true)
List<Task>findByName(@Param("name")String name);

Page<Task>findByAll(Pageable pageable);

@Query(name="Task.findById", nativeQuery = true)
@RestResource(exported = false)
Optional<Task>findById(@Param("id")long id);
```

`}`

Comment: Please format properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

```
Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract 
org.springframework.data.domain.Page 
com.book.todo.repository.TaskRepository.findByAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); 
No property 'all' found for type 'Task'
```

When using Spring Data, method naming is important. `findBy...` indicates you want to find by a property. So with `Page<Task> findByAll`, you're telling Spring Data to create the query `select * from Task where all = ?`

If you want to use paging, you need your repository to implement [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)), which already includes a `Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)` method.

Comment: If you are rewriting the methods to follow Spring Data JPA naming conventions, your changes are correct. Conventions suggest that method names follow a specific pattern so that Spring Data JPA can interpret them correctly and generate corresponding SQL queries.

Here's how the rewritten methods would look:

       Page<Task> findByIdIn(List<Integer> eventIds, Pageable pageable);
 Page<Task> findByNameIn(Collection<String> names, Pageable pageable);

Comment: Why do I think you're a bot?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider -- I have that impression, too... Esp. when looking at the question again.

Comment: I'm not a boot, I'm Brazilian I have difficulty with English